# Use custom annotation in hexMachina

Tags: annotations, haxe, hexmachina

I try to use custom annotation in hexMachina.

In one module, I register my metadata:

```
this._annotationProvider.registerMetaData("Url", this.urlProviderModel.getUrl)
```

And in a Command, executed in a Macro :

```
@Url("applicationConfig")
public var applicationConfigUrl:String;
```

The Macro is executed in context :

```
<state id="assemblingEnd" ref="applicationContext.state.ASSEMBLING_END">
    <enter command-class="app.adapter.bootstrap.BootstrapMacro" fire-once="true"/>
</state>
```

applicationConfigUrl has null

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AnnotationProvider](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMVC/blob/master/src/hex/metadata/AnnotationProvider.hx) delivers data based on domain references.

In the previous example, [metadata is registered on module's domain](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMVC/blob/master/src/hex/module/Module.hx#L51), and the BootstrapMacro instance is executed from the main application context's domain (its parent).

To fix the problem, I have registered the annotation to TopLevelDomain with :

```
AnnotationProvider.getAnnotationProvider().registerMetaData("Url", urlProviderModule.getUrlFunction());
```

With this kind of registration, the annotation will be available to every domain. This is because AnnotationProvider API provides automatic inheritance for every registration to all children domains, with cascading effect as well (children of children...).

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick addition, it's also possible to register from your main context without targeting the top-level domain.

```
AnnotationProvider.getAnnotationProvider( context.getDomain() ).registerMetaData("Url", urlProviderModule.getUrlFunction());
```

The unit tests can help to understand the behaviors. They are available [here.](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMVC/blob/a58873a9dd0efa7e9f920858313dd60663c45785/test/hex/metadata/AnnotationProviderTest.hx)

Comment: And how do you get the context from the module itself or from a service? It doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Imho, it would be a bad practice to retrieve the main context from an internal component, because each component should be a blind black box without any knowledge about the global world.




BTW, if you want to retrieve this information, here's a quick example extracted from unit tests:
`var annotationProvider = applicationAssembler.getContextFactory( applicationAssembler.getApplicationContext( "applicationContext" ) ).getAnnotationProvider();
  annotationProvider.registerMetaData( "color", this.getColorByName );`